# Flowable 7 with Spring Boot 3: No qualifying bean of type 'org.flowable.engine.RepositoryService'

Tags: flowable

I am updating some applications to the latest Spring Boot (3.1.0) and in one of them, I am using Flowable.

The point is, that after upgrading some versions on my `pom.xml` I get a `No qualifying bean of type 'org.flowable.engine.RepositoryService'` issue. I have this error in my tests and when I try to run the application itself. I have changed the Flowable version to `7.0.0.M1` as this version is defined as:

> This is the first milestone for version 7 of the Flowable Engines
> focusing on the Spring Boot 3, Spring 6 and Java 17 upgrade.

As I am using two different git branches, if I go back to the previous version (Flowable 6.8.0 and Spring Boot 2.6.4) is working fine. Then I assuming that, or the version is still not ready (is a Milestone 1, understandable) or some extra configuration is different, but I am not able to find any specific documentation.

Do somebody know if version 7.0.0.M1 is usable? My expectations [are not high](https://forum.flowable.org/t/spring-boot-3-migration/9838), but maybe somebody has already good experience with it. There is some specific information when migrating to Sprint Boot 3?

I am not able to find any specific documentation or feed-back about it.

Comment: This should work without any special changes. Can you try setting debug to true and check what the auto configuration report looks like? If you look for RepositoryService you will see why it isn't created. Also look for the ProcessEngineConfiguration to see why the bean is not being created

Comment: I think that is not as easy. The point that Flowable v7.0.0.M1 states that is focusing on migration, means that an effort has been made by Flowable team. And If you update an existing project to Sprint Boot 3, it stops working.

Comment: It is difficult to help you when you don't provide further information. When you start a simple new Spring Boot 3 project and add the `flowable-spring-boot-starter` dependency the `RepositoryService` is available for injection. That makes it hard to reproduce what you are seeing without further insights.

Comment: But from your comment, seems that Flowable v7.0.0.M1 is usable. Or are you using a previous version from Flowable?

Comment: Flowable v7.0.0.M1 is indeed usable with Spring Boot 3. That's why I pointed out what to look for to see why it isn't working for you

Comment: Ok, then I will continue exploring why is not working. The Link I have posted on the question is telling `the form and content engines are not yet there` for example.

Comment: Have been using version 7.0.0.M1 without any hiccups so far. perhaps you could share some code around your project dependency configuration.

Comment: If you say that is working, I will first put more effort to check what has been changed. And later, update the question if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems a dependency problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flowable</groupId>
        <artifactId>flowable-form-spring-configurator</artifactId>
        <version>${flowable.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency version is `6.8.0` as does not exist yet version `7.0.0.M1` . Probably is the one that is causing the problem, but I need it. I will keep everything on version `6.8.0` by now.